# How do I get the coordinates of the Maijor grid on a chart control in C#?

Tags: c#

Is there any way to get the coordinates of the X axis of the vertical Maijor Grid shown in the chart below?
For example, 11, 20, 32......... in order from left to right.
Dividing the length of the X axis of the chart plot area by the number of Maijor Grids did not give the exact coordinates (because the undivided portion was truncated?).

[image: My Chart]